# Implementing statistic functions using iterators in C++

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I need to use basic statistic functions (like mean, variance, quantile) for collections defined using standard iterators (e.g. for subarrays of a `boost::multi_array`). Are these implemented somewhere in the standard libraries or boost?

Even if there is a ready-made implementation, I found this interesting exercise in templates. Because these methods don't have any parameters with the same type as the result, I tried to define them as follows:

```
template<class TIter>
TIter::value_type mean(TIter begin, TIter end)
{
    int n = 1;
    TIter::value_type result = *begin;
    begin++;
    while(begin!=end)
    {
        n++;
        result+=*begin;
        begin++;
    }
    return result/n;
}
```

but it obviously doesn't compile:

```
stats.h:17:1: error: need ‘typename’ before ‘TIter::value_type’ because ‘TIter’ is a dependent scope
```

What would be the best way to define such a function?

Comment: The compiler's telling you the exact problem. You need to change: `TIter::value_type` to `typename TIter::value_type`. Then you can replace the whole thing with `std::accumulate(begin, end, 0.0)/std::distance(begin, end);`. Oh, you might also want to look at the [Boost Statistical Accumulators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/accumulators/user_s_guide.html#accumulators.user_s_guide.the_statistical_accumulators_library) library.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Why didn't you write this as an answer?

Comment: @dogjones: because I'm lazy and stupid?